# Django templatetags seem to make the prefetch_related useless

Tags: django, prefetch, templatetags

When I add a filter based on a template tag ("provinceonly") to my Django template, debug-toolbar indicates that the database is hit 115 time instead of 5 previously.

Is it a well-known issue ? I cant' find a way to prefetch correctly the required information to reduce the number of hits. Is there something I can do about it ?

---

Template:

```
{% for country in allcountries %}
    {% for province in country.fkcountrysecondaries.all|provinceonly %}
        {{ province.basicname }}
            {% for populatedplace in province.fkprovince.fkprovincesecondaries.all %}
                    {{ populatedplace.basicname }}
            {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Template tag:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.filter
def provinceonly(thelist):
    return thelist.filter(type="province")
```

View:

```
def indexconsistencycheck(request):
    allcountries = NaturalEarthCountry.objects.all().prefetch_related('fkcountrysecondaries__fkprovince__fkprovincesecondaries').select_related('fkcountrymain')
```

Model:

```
class NaturalEarthAll(models.Model):
    fkcountry = models.OneToOneField(NaturalEarthCountry, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="fkcountrymain")
    fkprovince = models.OneToOneField(NaturalEarthProvince, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="fkprovincemain")
    fktouristicarea = models.ForeignKey(TouristicArea, blank=True, null=True, related_name='relatednatmerged', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    fkcountrysecondary = models.ForeignKey(NaturalEarthCountry, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="fkcountrysecondaries")
    fkprovincesecondary = models.ForeignKey(NaturalEarthProvince, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="fkprovincesecondaries")
```

Comment: when you apply `filter` operation on a prefetched queryset, it creates a new queryset and loses all the prefetched data. What you can do is to not use the template tag and put the filtered queryset in the context.

Comment: Ok, very clear. Thank you for your comments. I therefore performed the main queryset on provinces (and not more on countries) so that I don't need anymore the templatetag filter. I will post the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Sachin, the templatetag generates a new queryset which loses prefetched data. I therefore had to perform the main queryset directly on the model  I needed to filter (provinces) and not on the previous one (countries), and then regrouped the results by country.

Thanks a lot

view:

```
allprovinces_list = NaturalEarthMerged.objects.filter(type="province").order_by('fkcountrysecondary__name').prefetch_related('fkprovince__fkprovincesecondaries', 'fkcountrysecondary__fkcountrymain').select_related('fkcountrysecondary')
```

template:

```
{% regroup allprovinces by fkcountrysecondary.name as countrylist %}
{% for listofprovinces in countrylist %}
    {{ listofprovinces.grouper }}
    {% for province in listofprovinces.list %}
        {{ province.basicname }}
        {% for populatedplace in province.fkprovince.fkprovincesecondaries.all %}
            {{ populatedplace.basicname }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```